# Bazel: Include runfiles in container_image

Tags: docker, containers, bazel

When creating Docker images using the `container_image` rule, necessary runfiles are not present in the image. The same is true for `pkg_tar` rules, which, it seems, is actually the problem.

With the following `BUILD` file, I would expect the `sh_binary` *tool_b* to appear in the runfiles of *tool_a*.

```
container_image(
    name = "my image",
    base = "@bash//image",
    directory = "/usr/local/opt",
    files = [":tool_a"],
)

sh_binary(
    name = "tool_a",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    srcs = ["tool_a.sh"],
    data = [":tool_b"],
)

sh_binary(
    name = "tool_b",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    srcs = ["tool_b.sh"],
)
```

The image however only contains `tool_a.sh` and the `tool_a` wrapper.

How can I include the runfiles, too?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't out of the box. This is a [longstanding defect](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/671) in the packaging rules.

Comment: I've seen that thread before. Too bad the change was abandoned. Is it possible to workaround this somehow?